# Mono.Cecil Import List Enumerator

Tags: .net, mono, mono.cecil

I'm doing a bit of IL weaving with Mono.Cecil, and I'm running into this issue:

```
Member 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator' is declared in
another module and needs to be imported
```

How do you go about importing the module that has the list enumerator?

I have a `TypeReference` (System.Collections.Generic.List`1< blah >) which I'm using to get an enumerator, like so:

```
var instanceType = (typeReference as GenericInstanceType);
var list = instanceType.Resolve();

MethodDefinition getEnumerator;
if (!list.TryGetMethod("GetEnumerator", out getEnumerator))
    throw ...
```

... where `TryGetMethod` is a custom extension that searches the type in question for a method with that name.

I then use the getEnumerator further down in the code, like so:

```
instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Callvirt, getEnumerator));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. To get an enumerator for a list, you need to get a `MethodReference` for the `GetEnumerator` method, like so:

```
Type listType = typeof (List<>);

MethodReference getEnumerator = moduleDefinition
    .Import(listType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator"));
```